# threejs same renderer show in multiple canvases

Tags: canvas, three.js, renderer

Can Threejs renderer render same scene in multiple canvases, so I want to render once and show it in two canvases. Note, that I dont want to render it twice, I just need to reflect one canvas into other. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite simple and it doesn't involve three.js anymore but simply copying one canvas output to another canvas.

https://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/5357/

```
    // copy source canvas to the other canvas after each render iteration
    pipctx.drawImage(renderer.domElement, 0, 0, 200, 200);
```

**Update**

Here's a solution with better performance(for Chrome and Firefox but not Edge yet):

1. Capture stream from the Three's canvas element

   ```
   dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(renderer.domElement.captureStream(45));
   ```
2. Attach that stream to `<video>`'s src attribute

   ```
   pip = document.createElement('video');
   pip.style.width = pip.style.height = '200px';
   document.body.appendChild(pip);
   pip.src = dataUrl;
   pip.play();
   ```

This way you don't have to refresh mirrored elements after every frame render. They will automatically keep up to date with the stream captured from the source canvas. This solution will need fallback to the version above for browsers where `captureStream` is not available. Example showing 100 video elements reflecting what's in main Three's canvas:

https://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/5359/

Comment: Thank you Pawel, Can you please say me , will it change fps rate ?

Comment: @Gor it depends on number of copies and their resolution. Two copies will not have much impact but 100 will. Also see my update. It shows how to have multiple copies of the canvas without having to refresh them manually.